# vertical-align:middle on a div within a container

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am having some trouble with div positioning. I'm working on a comment system in wich comments can get upvotes and downvotes. For every comment the up/down vote-buttons needs to be left of my comment text, and vertically aligned in the middle of my comment-container div. (regardless of how big the comment is)

At the moment it wont work properly, because the buttons wont get to the middle of the div. (see: http://jsfiddle.net/mcSfe/1838/)

In the testcase i want the leftside to be stretched all the way down, and the red box vertically centered in the middle of the leftside. vertical-align, and display:table-cell, did not brought the right result..

Here is my test html code:

```
<div class="commentContainer">
<div class="leftside">
    <div class="innerleft">
        test
    </div>
</div>
<div class ="CommentBox">
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>this is my comment</p>
    <p>another line of comment</p>
</div>
```

and here is my test css code:

```
div.commentContainer{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
div.leftside {
    float:left;
    width: 50px;
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
}
div.innerleft {
    float:left;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left:13px;
    background: red;
}
div.CommentBox {
    float:right;
    width:200px; 
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float` from `.commentbox` and `.leftside` and add `display:table-cell` with `vertical-align:middle`

```
div.commentContainer{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
div.leftside {
    width: 50px;
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
}
div.innerleft {
    float:left;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left:13px;
    background: red;
}
div.CommentBox {
    width:200px; 
    background-color:green;
    display: table-cell
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iRucITe/2/)**

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I'm working this out in Dreamweaver, but my design view is not showing this correctly. Any idea where the problem might be? (i ran the html and css through w3c validator and it doesn't seem to contain mistakes)?

Comment: Somwtime dreamweaver design view wont show up the things as it is. Even I use dreamweaver and I never look up in design view.

Answer (score 0):

LIke this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcSfe/1839/)**

**css**

```
div.commentContainer{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid blue;
    display:table;
}
div.leftside {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 50px;
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;

}
div.innerleft {

    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left:13px;
    background: red;
        vertical-align:middle;
}
div.CommentBox {
    display:table-cell;
    width:200px; 
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of using floats, use `inline-block`.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/kMfTN/)

**CSS**

```
div.commentContainer{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
div.leftside {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 50px;
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
}
div.innerleft {
    float:left;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left:13px;
    background: red;
}
div.CommentBox {
    display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
    width:200px; 
    background-color:green;
}
```

Issues regarding `inline-block` whitespace can be addressed separately.